# List not copying (empty)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
import sys
import os.path
import ConfigParser
import copy
import time
import colorama
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init() 

#init variables
discoveredelements = []
discoveredgroups = []
combo = []
savefile = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
os.chdir(os.getcwd())

#init other stuff
class style:
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   END = '\033[0m'

def combos():
    #all combos
    combo.append(('Air', 'Air', 'Wind'))
    combo.append(('Earth', 'Earth', 'Pressure'))
    combo.append(('Fire', 'Fire', 'Explosion'))
    combo.append(('Water', 'Water', 'Sea'))
    combo.append(('Air', 'Earth', 'Dust'))
    combo.append(('Air', 'Fire', 'Energy'))
    combo.append(('Air', 'Water', 'Steam'))
    combo.append(('Earth', 'Fire', 'Lava'))
    combo.append(('Earth', 'Water', 'Swamp'))
    combo.append(('Fire', 'Water', 'Alcohol'))

def mainmenu():
    print(style.BOLD + "ALCHEMY" + style.END)
    print(style.BOLD + "Load Game" + style.END)
    print(style.BOLD + "New Game" + style.END)
    print(style.BOLD + "Exit" + style.END)
    print("Type \"load\" or \"new\" or \"exit\" ")
    mainmenuinput = raw_input()
    if mainmenuinput == "exit":
        sys.exit()
    elif mainmenuinput == "load":
        if os.path.exists('save.ini'):
            savefile.read('save.ini')
            discoveredelements = savefile.get('Elements','discoveredelements')
            print("Game Loaded")
            rungame()
        else:
            print("Save file not found, check file directory or start a new game.")
            mainmenu()
    elif mainmenuinput == "new":
        if os.path.exists("save.ini"):
            print("Current save file will be overwritten. Proceed?")
            print("Y or N")
            overwriteinput = raw_input()
            if overwriteinput == "Y":
                newgame()
                rungame()
            elif overwriteinput == "N":
                mainmenu()
        else:
            newgame()
            rungame()


def newgame():
    save = open('save.ini','w')
    #reset data
    savefile.add_section('Elements')
    savefile.add_section('Groups')
    savefile.set('Elements','discoveredelements',"")
    savefile.set('Groups','discoveredgroups',"")
    #adds the default elements
    discoveredelements.append("Air")
    discoveredelements.append("Earth")
    discoveredelements.append("Fire")
    discoveredelements.append("Water")
    savefile.set('Elements','discoveredelements',discoveredelements)
    discoveredgroups.append("Air")
    discoveredgroups.append("Earth")
    discoveredgroups.append("Fire")
    discoveredgroups.append("Water")
    savefile.set('Groups','discoveredgroups',discoveredgroups)
    savefile.write(save)
    save.close()
    print("Game Loaded")

def gameloop():
    #actual gameplay
    print("Type two elements (seperately) or \"list\" or \"hint\" or \"save\" or \"exit\"")
    gameinput = raw_input()
    if gameinput == "list":
        displayelements = copy.copy(discoveredelements)
        print(','.join(map(str, displayelements)))
        gameloop()
    elif gameinput == "hint":
        if (time.time() - timerstart) >= 10:
            print('hint')
            timerstart = time.time()
            gameloop()
        else:
            print("Hint is still on cooldown")
            gameloop()
    elif gameinput == "save":
        savefile.set('Elements','discoveredelements',discoveredelements)
        savefile.set('Groups','discoveredgroups',discoveredgroups)
        print("Game saved")
    elif gameinput == "exit":
        savefile.read('save.ini')
        savelist = savefile.get('Elements','discoveredelements')
        if len(savelist) < len(discoveredelements):
            print("Game not saved! Do you wish to exit without saving?")
            print("Y or N")
            overwriteinput = raw_input()
            if overwriteinput == "Y":
                mainmenu()
            else:
                gameloop()
    else:
        elementA = gameinput
        elementB = raw_input()
        if (elementA in discoveredelements) and (elementB in discoveredelements):
                i = 0
                created = 0 
                while True:
                    if (combo[i][0] == elementA and combo[i][1] == elementB) or (combo[i][1] == elementA and combo[i][0] == elementB):
                        print("You created " + combo[i][2])
                        discoveredelements.append(combo[i][2])
                        created = 1
                        break
                    i += 1
                    if i == len(combo):
                        break
                if created == 0:
                    print("No elements created")
                    gameloop()
        else:
            print("Error, using non-existent or not yet discovered elements")
            gameloop()

def rungame():
    #initializing game
    timerstart = time.time()
    displayelements = copy.copy(discoveredelements)
    print(','.join(map(str, displayelements)))
    gameloop()

#game starts here
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
combos()
mainmenu()
```

When I type "load" into the console, nothing is outputted for displayelements. So I tried to see if the list contained anything (and if the copy.copy() worked or not) by doing print(displayelements) and it printed []
Then I checked if discoveredelements contained anything and it did:
['Air', 'Earth', 'Fire', 'Water']
Why isn't the copy.copy() working?

EDIT:
I declared discoveredelements  as global:

```
global discoveredelements
discoveredelements = []
```

The copying still doesn't work, displayelements is still an empty list.

Comment: By the way, `gameloop` isn't a loop - it's using recursion. The game will crash after 1000 moves.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 oh I didn't know, thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 0):

To assign to a global var in function you must declare is as global:

```
discoveredelements = []
def func():
    # a new var is created in the scope of this function
    discoveredelements = [1,2,3,4]
func()
print (discoveredelements)



discoveredelements = []
def func():
    # declare as global
    global discoveredelements
    # assign to the global var 
    discoveredelements = [1,2,3,4]
func()
print (discoveredelements)
```

Comment: i declared it as a global variable at it still doesn't print anything when i do print(displayelements)

Comment: Did you declare is as global **inside** de `mainmenu` function?

Comment: oh i didn't lol, thanks for the reply now it works!